wrong work horizontal listview scroll in SlidingUpPanel
I use sliding up panel
I have two listview. One inside other. First vertical, second horizontal. When swipe horizontal listview, SlidingUpPanel also moves, if vertical listview not long enough. How can i fix it?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter  Example"),
        ),
        body: SlidingUpPanel(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          minHeight: 80,
          maxHeight: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.8,
          panelBuilder: (ScrollController sc) => _panel(sc),
          body: Center(
            child: Text("This is the Widget behind the sliding panel"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _panel(ScrollController sc) {
  return ListView(
    controller: sc,
    children: List.generate(3, (index) {
      return const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 100,
          ));
    })
      ..add(SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: List.filled(
                  6, const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: FlutterLogo(size: 100)))))),
  );
}


https://imgur.com/a/Xs8RIjn
I think, i can block vertical scroll with this code if add scroll controller to horizontal listview, but i dont know how.
 late ScrollController _controller;
  bool isScrolling = false;

  void _handleScrollChange() {
    if (isScrolling != _controller.position.isScrollingNotifier.value) {
      setState(() {
        isScrolling = _controller.position.isScrollingNotifier.value;
      });
    }
  }

  void _handlePositionAttach(ScrollPosition position) {

    position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(_handleScrollChange);
  }

  void _handlePositionDetach(ScrollPosition position) {

    position.isScrollingNotifier.removeListener(_handleScrollChange);
  }```

